# Event ID: 1325, Source: ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

Tags: asp.net

**Could any One Help Me Identify the Error and suggest a solution Please.**

Log Name:      Application

Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

Date:          3/6/2015 7:28:58 AM

Event ID:      1325

Task Category: None

Level:         Error

Keywords:      Classic

User:          N/A

Computer:      XXX

Description:
An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT

Process ID: 13528

Exception: System.Threading.ThreadStateException

Message: Unable to retrieve thread information.

StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Thread.GetThreadStateNative()

at FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.NewDevice.Dispose()

at FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.NewDevice.Finalize()

```
Event Xml:

    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
        <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1325</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-06T13:28:58.000Z" />
        <EventRecordID>173806</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>379501-dy.ord.intensive.int</Computer>
        <Security />
      </System>
      <EventData>
        <Data>An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
```

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT

Process ID: 13528

Exception: System.Threading.ThreadStateException

Message: Unable to retrieve thread information.

```
StackTrace:    at System.Threading.Thread.GetThreadStateNative()

   at FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.NewDevice.Dispose()

   at FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.NewDevice.Finalize()</Data>

  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message today; my solution is to remove the module from my codebase. A tad extreme, but I don't want third-party modules that when they crash, kill the entire application pool.